# GCP Metadata Larger 256kb

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, cloud, fedora, fedora-coreos

i need to use metadata `user-data` for few instances (on linux FCOS) larger than 256kb, but i got:

> is too large: maximum size 262144 character

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/setting-custom-metadata#limitations

It's possible to:

- anyhow use larger than 256kb `metadata` `user-data`?
- or fetch `user-data` for instance from a remote server e.g.: I could upload this `user-data` to any HTTP server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found.. solution via remote ignition file.

I tried increasing the 256kb per single metadata limit via google support but they cant increase this for me.

Workaround via remote ignition file:

1. In Fedora CoreOS `user-data` add the below snippet
2. On Nginx share a big ignition file larger than 256kb
3. Start instance, instance will connect to remote Nginx to get big ignition file

```json
{
  "ignition": {
    "config": {
      "merge": [
        {
          "source": "http://xxxx/file.ign"
        }
      ]
    },
    "version": "3.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @AhmedSbai described more